# Insert Picture from Picturebox to excel

Tags: excel, oledb, picturebox

I have a code which inserting all information from textboxes to excel file.
What I trying to do to using this code also add a picture from picturebox.
So in each row in the right column will be a picture.
But I having a problem to adjust a code.
Could anyone help me with that?

Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=DATA\DATA.xlsm;Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""

```
        'Create an INSERT INTO SQL statement
        Dim insertStatement As String = "INSERT INTO [DATA$] ([WEEK], [DATE], [PART NAME], [PART NUMBER], [REASON FOR SCRAP], [LINE], [MACHINE], [TOOLING], [MTO], [QTY], [WHO SCRAP IT]) VALUES ('" + WEEK_TEXT.Text + "','" + DATEE_TEXT.Text + "','" + PARTNAME_TEXT.Text + "','" + PARTNUMBER_TEXT.Text + "','" + SCRAP_REASON_TEXT.Text + "','" + LINE_text.Text + "','" + MACHINE_TEXT.Text + "','" + SIDE_TEXT.Text + "','" + MTO_TEXT.Text + "','" + QUANTITY_TEXT.Text + "','" + TL_TS_TEXT.Text + "')"
        Dim insertStatement1 As String = "INSERT INTO [QAD DATA$] ([WEEK], [DATE], [PART NAME], [QAD NUMBER], [REASON FOR SCRAP], [LINE], [MACHINE], [TOOLING], [MTO], [QTY], [WHO SCRAP IT]) VALUES ('" + WEEK_TEXT.Text + "','" + DATEE_TEXT.Text + "','" + PictureBox1.I + "','" + QAD_NUMBER_TEXT.Text + "','" + SCRAP_REASON_TEXT.Text + "','" + LINE_text.Text + "','" + MACHINE_TEXT.Text + "','" + SIDE_TEXT.Text + "','" + MTO_TEXT.Text + "','" + QUANTITY_TEXT.Text + "','" + TL_TS_TEXT.Text + "')"

        'Create a connection object to connect to the Excel Workbook
        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        Dim connection1 As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        'Create a command object that will execute the insert statement
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(insertStatement, connection)
        Dim command1 As New OleDbCommand(insertStatement1, connection1)


        'Open the connection, execute the statement and close the connection
        connection.Open()
        connection1.Open()

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery()


        connection.Close()
        connection1.Close()
        'Dispose of the connection and command objects
        connection.Dispose()
        command.Dispose()
        command1.Dispose()
```